# Error with keys when running terraform apply

Tags: terraform

When running terraform apply I get an error with keys. I am just learning terraform. I can't seem to find a solution online on how to fix this issue:

```
   machine:terraform$ terraform apply
   aws_instance.nginix: Creating...
     ami:                          "" => "ami-d1180894"
     associate_public_ip_address:  "" => "<computed>"
     availability_zone:            "" => "<computed>"
     ebs_block_device.#:           "" => "<computed>"
     ephemeral_block_device.#:     "" => "<computed>"
     instance_state:               "" => "<computed>"
     instance_type:                "" => "t2.nano"
     ipv6_address_count:           "" => "<computed>"
     ipv6_addresses.#:             "" => "<computed>"
     key_name:                     "" => "terraform-keys2"
     network_interface.#:          "" => "<computed>"
     network_interface_id:         "" => "<computed>"
     placement_group:              "" => "<computed>"
     primary_network_interface_id: "" => "<computed>"
     private_dns:                  "" => "<computed>"
     private_ip:                   "" => "<computed>"
     public_dns:                   "" => "<computed>"
     public_ip:                    "" => "<computed>"
     root_block_device.#:          "" => "<computed>"
     security_groups.#:            "" => "<computed>"
     source_dest_check:            "" => "true"
     subnet_id:                    "" => "<computed>"
     tenancy:                      "" => "<computed>"
     volume_tags.%:                "" => "<computed>"
     vpc_security_group_ids.#:     "" => "<computed>"
   Error applying plan:

   1 error(s) occurred:

   * aws_instance.nginix: 1 error(s) occurred:

   * aws_instance.nginix: Error launching source instance: InvalidKeyPair.NotFound: The key pair 'terraform-keys2' does not exist
    status code: 400, request id: 993cc401-4c7a-4e4b-9630-71bc4b5729b0

   Terraform does not automatically rollback in the face of errors.
   Instead, your Terraform state file has been partially updated with
   any resources that successfully completed. Please address the error
   above and apply again to incrementally change your infrastructure.
```

I tried going to AWS console and creating a keypair but that does not seem to help

Comment: Did you create the keypair in the same region that you're running Terraform against? And is it named `terraform-keys2`?

Comment: I went to the AWS console and created a keypair through the console. I did not see an option to create it in a region

Comment: You have to set the region [as shown in their documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsconsolehelpdocs/latest/gsg/getting-started.html#select-region). AWS keypairs are unique to each region. Alternative, you can create the keypair as part of your Terraform.

Comment: @wkl's comment saved me a lot of time. keypair's have to be in the same region.

Answer (score 12):

From your machine, create the keypair using the command as follow `ssh-keygen -f terraform-keys2`

then your config should have resource `aws_key_pair` as below to it in aws

```
resource "aws_key_pair" "terraform-keys2" {
  key_name = "terraform-keys2"
  public_key = "terraform-keys2.pub"
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem and the solution given above worked great for me :)

Comment: It seems that the content of the key needs to be given, not the path: `public_key = "${file("${path.root}/terraform-keys2.pub")}"` should work

Answer (score 10):

With this error, please check if you have created the keypair `terraform-keys2` in the region you are working on.

> aws_instance.nginix: Error launching source instance: InvalidKeyPair.NotFound: The key pair `terraform-keys2` does not exist
>   status code: 400, request id: 993cc401-4c7a-4e4b-9630-71bc4b5729b0

Answer (score 2):

One possible reason for this problem could be that you're referring to a key which was created in different region over aws console, while in your terraform code you're trying to call it from different region.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**
Please run this below command, You should have installed aws-cli.

```
aws ec2 import-key-pair --public-key-material file://~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub --key-name my-key
```

Answer (score 1):

This error might also happen if you reference your aws_key_pair resource in quotation marks, like this:

```
resource "aws_key_pair" "mykey" {
  key_name    = "mykey"
  public_key  = file(var.PATH_TO_PUBLIC_KEY)
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = var.AMIS[var.AWS_REGION]
  instance_type = "t4g.micro"
  key_name      = "aws_key_pair.mykey.key_name"
  ...
}
```

I have put the qutation marks by an impulsive accident an it took me a while to notice my sysntax mistake. So it should look like this:

```
...
key_name      = aws_key_pair.mykey.key_name
...
```

Answer (score 0):

for associating a key-pair to my EC2 I created a variable

```
variable "instance_keypair" {
      description = "Instance key-pair that need to be associated with EC2 Instance"
      type = string
      default = "ec2_devops_0"
    }
```

and then I referred it in my EC2 resource

```
resource "aws_instance" "myec2vm" {
    ami = data.aws_ami.amzlinux2.id
    instance_type = var.instance_type
    key_name = var.instance_keypair
    vpc_security_group_ids = [ aws_security_group.vpc-ssh.id, aws_security_group.vpc-web.id ]
    tags = {
      "Name" = "EC2 Demo 2"
    }
}
```

for this, the key should be valid and should exist with your account.